# Ideal bitmap size for optimal GPU performance?

Tags: c++, graphics, gpu

I know that when dealing with the graphics card, one needs to provide bitmaps with a power of 2. 1,2,4,8,16,32... I am planning on making a tile based project, only I needed to know if there were any limitations in providing a gigantic bitmap to the graphics card. What are the pros/cons of using small/large bitmaps? Is there a more preferable bitmap size I should be using?

Comment: Isn't that likely to be specific to a particular GPU / chipset combination?

Comment: Maybe so, but there must be a preferred size bitmap size for cards with 128MB and up. I would be very interested in seeing the pros/cons.

Comment: I don't think there are limitations in size and indeed the best performance should be to send the full bitmap in one go.

Comment: Glad to hear that since I need a large bitmap for my project. The bigger the chunks, the better for my program.

Comment: yeah, the gpu works better with non-frequend but massive send of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when dealing with modern GPUs, larger datasize is better.  You don't say what API you're using (OpenGL, CUDA, etc.), but you can think of it like this:

```
chunk_time = overhead_time + (num_of_elements/num_of_chunks) * per_element_time
total_time = chunk_time * num_of_chunks
```

You'll get the overhead for both memory transfer and code execution for each chunk of data you send through.  You might have other limitations depending on how huge your data is: the max texture bind size in OpenGL, for example, is implementation dependent.  I think 1k by 1k should be a safe minimum with hardware from the last 5 years or so, but recent cards can handle 8k by 8k.